# Why do I get compiler errors when I try to use print() in my Xcode?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to use `print()` to debug, but every time I try, I get some compiler errors.

For example this is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class LoginInputs: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    print(email)
}
```

And these are the errors I get:

> Cannot find type 'email' in scope

> Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration

> Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'

Another frequent error that shows up in SwiftUI views is "Expressions are not allowed at the top level".

Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Your code is "nowhere", it's "floating". It needs to be in a "function".

Comment: "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" says it all.

Comment: Review the fundamentals of Swift at:  https://www.swift.org/documentation/
It is crucial to understand the basic concepts, before going on with writing swift code.
Review also the docs about SwiftUI at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you could try something like this to print the value of `email` every time it changes:

```
class LoginInputs: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email = "" {
        didSet {
           print(email)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The print can also be adding a custom getter